# android how to work with animations

Tags: android, animation

I want animation, for example in my screen 4 birds should be there. and at a time 3 birds are visible. They are flying continuously.
How can i do that please give me answer.
How bird fly with wings I cant get that one please give me answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need **AnimationDrawable** for your purpose

Here is the tutorial for this [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)